# Android Fragment Life Cycle and Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a nested fragment that is supposed to show a Google map. When the activity is first created, the main fragment is added, which then instantiates the nested map fragment. This works correctly.

However, if the user leaves the app (placing it into the background) and then later comes back to it, the nested map fragment is no longer displayed. It's as if someone called `map.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` (not View.GONE) on it (except that this wasn't called - I'm just stating it to put the issue in context).

Here is the relevant code for the first fragment (note that I'm leaving a lot of code out, so please don't worry if there are any variables that aren't initialized in what you see here):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("resume", "today onCreateView");
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);    
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        addMapFragment(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), location.getLocationName());
    }

    private void addMapFragment(LatLng latLng, String marker_name) {

        Log.d("resume", Double.toString(latLng.latitude));

        Bundle mapBundle = new Bundle();
        mapBundle.putDouble("lat", latLng.latitude);
        mapBundle.putDouble("lng", latLng.longitude);
        mapBundle.putString("marker_title", marker_name);

        // capture this for use in getting directions if requested
        destinationLatLng = new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

        mMapFragment = new MapFragment();
        mMapFragment.setArguments(mapBundle);

        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_today, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        Log.d("resume", "map added");
    }
```

**fragment_today.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mysite.myapp.Activities.ViewControllers.TodayFragment"
    android:id="@+id/today_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_frame_today"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_today"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp" />

       <!-- lots of other textviews follow. omitted for brevity-->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
```

Then, finally, in the map fragment, I have this code. I've played around with where I put the code to generate the map (switching between onCreateView and onResume). I'm putting as much code in onResume as possible. Note that none of the values ever changes between when the user places the app into the background and when they return to it, so that's not an issue:

**MapFragment.java**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("resume", "map oncreateview");

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        // set the title text (if given by parent fragment)
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        if (bundle != null) {

            if (bundle.containsKey("lat") && bundle.containsKey("lng")) {    
                myLocation = new LatLng(bundle.getDouble("lat"), bundle.getDouble("lng"));
            }

            if (bundle.containsKey("marker_title"))
                markerTitle = bundle.getString("marker_title");

        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("resume", "map onResume");

        if (myLocation != null && markerTitle != null) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(workoutLocation)
                    .zoom(12)
                    .tilt(30)
                    .build();

            GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_map)).getMap();

            Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(workoutLocation)
                            .title(markerTitle)
            );
            marker.showInfoWindow();

            map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }
```

At runtime, this all generates the following output:

*on initial instantiation*

> today onResume 
> current
>   
> 44.915647 
> map added 
> map oncreateview 
> map onResume

*when the app goes into the background*

> today onPause 
> onStop

*when the app comes back into the foregound*
today onCreateView

> map oncreateview 
> today onCreateView
>   
> Activity.onPostResume() called 
> today onResume 
> current
>   
> 44.915647 
> map added 
> map onResume 
> today onResume
>   
> current 
> 44.915647 
> map added 
> map oncreateview 
> map
>   onResume 
> map oncreateview 
> map onResume

I think that this all looks good, although it's curious that 'map oncreateview' and 'map onResume' appears twice (I don't think that this is an issue).

Long post, but an interesting dilemma. Thanks to anyone who got this far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the new API which gets your map asynchronously.

Have a reference to your Google Map object. In onResume(), check if it is null and then get your map.

Also I suggest adding your child map as you would a regular fragment.  That is, instead of using a fragment in layout use a FrameLayout and add (Support)MapFragment to it. I've found a lot of problems when using nested child fragment in my fragments.

So, I suggest something like this:

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(){
    if(googleMap == null){
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        // mapContainerLayout would be some FrameLayout to replace the <fragment> you use for map
        getChildFragmentManager.beginTransaction.replace(R.id.mapContainerLayout, mapFragment, "MapTag").commit;
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    this.googleMap = map;
    // Do other stuff as needed
}
```

Then simply call setUpMapIfNeeded() in onResume().

EDIT: change your fragmentManager to getChildFragmentManager();

Comment: Good suggestion. Wasn't even aware of the `getMapAsync()` method. Unfortunately, I revised my MapFragment class to implement this, but I still get exactly same result. I can't change the nested fragment since it is part of an overall app architecture decision that would have significant repercussions elsewhere. I'd rather just leave this issue as it is if it came to that.

Comment: Try changing your fragmentManager to getChildFragmentManager(). Not sure what else could be. Also, you're always adding new map fragment in onResume(). The code above was meant for your main fragment. I didn't realize you had a separate MapFragment class.

Comment: That was it. It was nothing more than calling `getChildFragmentManager()`. Wow, I can't believe how much time I spent on this. Please post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Edited the original answer. Glad to be of help.